# Magento2 - VAT Price not including the final price

Tags: magento2, checkout, vat

My Product unit price **€ 13.50**.

**9% VAT** apply for that product but edit cart page display the **VAT** amount, but it's not added to the **Subtotal**.

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Tax settings. It seems like your catalog prices are already including tax.

You can change this setting from here.

Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Price Display settings

[image]

This setting is used on catalog. There are many other settings for subtotal, Grandtotal etc. Please take a look at Shopping Cart Display Settings.

[image]